# Don't want an ID column

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to write a GORM domain object to work with a legacy database table which has no ID column.  Reading the doc for ID, I don't see any obvious way to do this.  http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html  when I try:

```
static mapping = {
    id false
}
```

I get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: id
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible for a Grails Domain to have no 'id'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582904/is-it-possible-for-a-grails-domain-to-have-no-id)

Comment: If your legacy table has a primary key (it may even work with unique) column other than id you may be able to map id to it

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/GORM.html#tableAndColumnNames

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't do that.
If you use Hibernate you need a primary key column.
Here is what the hibernate documentation said:

> Mapped classes must declare the primary key column of the database table

Here is the reference http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id